# Magic mock assert_called_once vs assert_called_once_with weird behaviour

Tags: python, unit-testing, magicmock

I am noticing a weird behavior with `assert_called_once` and `assert_called_once_with` in python. This is my real simple test:

File module/a.py

```
from .b import B

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = B("hi")

    def call_b_hello(self):
        print(self.b.hello())
```

File module/b.py

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(self, string):
        print("created B")
        self.string = string;

    def hello(self):
        return self.string
```

These are my tests:

```
import unittest
from mock import patch
from module.a import A    

class MCVETests(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('module.a.B')   
    def testAcallBwithMockPassCorrect(self, b1):
        a = A()
        b1.assert_called_once_with("hi")
        a.call_b_hello()
        a.b.hello.assert_called_once()

    @patch('module.a.B')
    def testAcallBwithMockPassCorrectWith(self, b1):
        a = A()
        b1.assert_called_once_with("hi")
        a.call_b_hello()
        a.b.hello.assert_called_once_with()

    @patch('module.a.B')
    def testAcallBwithMockFailCorrectWith(self, b1):
        a = A()
        b1.assert_called_once_with("hi")
        a.b.hello.assert_called_once_with()

    @patch('module.a.B')
    def testAcallBwithMockPassWrong(self, b1):
        a = A()
        b1.assert_called_once_with("hi")
        a.b.hello.assert_called_once()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

My problem as stated in the name of the function is:

- Test 1 passes correctly
- Test 2 passes correctly
- Test 3 fails correctly (I've removed the call to b)
- Test 4 passes I am not sure why.

Am I doing something wrong? I am not sure but reading the documentation [docs python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html):

> assert_called_once(*args, **kwargs)
>
> Assert that the mock was called exactly once.

Comment: I can't actually reproduce this. Both 3 and 4 fail in my case. What version of Python and what version of the `mock` library do you use? I tested with Python 3.6 (and used the stdlib `unittest.mock`).

Comment: I was using python2.7, I'll change the code and check with python3.5 thanks :)

Comment: In 3.5 that function does not exist, so I will solve the problem using this way:


assert a.b.hello.call_count == 1

https://engineeringblog.yelp.com/2015/02/assert_called_once-threat-or-menace.html

Comment: I can't reproduce this in Python 2.7 *either*, using `mock` version 2.0.0.

Comment: I am not sure what to say. I had this issue and I am rewriting all the tests to fix the issue. In version 3.5 I get:

    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: assert_called_once


In version 2.7 I get pass. I don't have access to version 3.6. Please close/delete the question if it is inappropriate, the fix for me is to use a workaround at this point :)

Comment: I didn't say it was inappropriate. I just can't reproduce your problem. I stated the Python and library versions; when I put your `a.py` and `b.py` into a directory `module` (with an empty `__init__.py` then use `python2.7 tests.py` to run your `TestCase`s, I get the expected 2 failures.

Comment: And indeed, in Python 3.5 you get an `AttributeError`, but you can install `mock` in Python3.5 too. :-) I just did, and I get the expected 2 assertion errors.

Comment: Yeah for environment problem I can't install anything on the machines, so I'll have to cope with python2.7/3.5 and mock 1.0.1 :D this looks a version problem that was fixed but I can't really enjoy the fix :)

Answer (score 10):

This is old, but for others landing here...

For python < 3.6, `assert_called_once` isn't a thing and so you're actually making a mocked function call which doesn't error

Please see: [Mocking Mistakes](https://web.archive.org/web/20210919045841/http://engineroom.trackmaven.com/blog/mocking-mistakes/)

You can check the call count instead.

Comment: This is old, but assert_called_once() has been a thing since python version 3.6.

Comment: So before that we have `assert mock.call_count == 1`.